# How to axios DELETE with header when I'm getting 401 all the time?

Tags: javascript, spring, rest, spring-boot, axios

I have a problem with axios call DELETE. When I try to delete entity via postman everything goes fine, from my axios I can post/get/patch entity but delete throws 401 even if passing null instead of payload. A lot of variations have been tried but without positive result.

Best regards!

```
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let id=payload.id;
                let url="http://localhost:8080/cars/"+id
                let config = {
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem('token'),
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                      }
                    }  

                axios.delete(url, payload, config)
                .then(({data,status}) => {
                    if(status === 200){
                        resolve(true);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error=> {
                    reject(error);
                })
            }
```

Comment: 401 is Unauthorized meaning your localStorage.getItem('token') returns token that is invalid for the backend.

Comment: the problem is probably in your backend code. the auth middleware is returning 401. check if the token is being passed with the request

Comment: My backend see null instead of token. I don't know why and only in this case, because other requests like patch/get sent simultaneously works great and token is present...

Answer (score 1):

I got it! In this case axios request should look like this, because axios in this method may have different approach with exposing his headers or something like that I dont know.. but if you pass everything like this then it will work. It's something like only allowed 2 objects in delete method(url, data) where data may include headers instead of 3 objects allowed like in post/delete/patch method where (url,payload,headers) are allowed

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    let id=payload.id;
                    let url="http://localhost:8080/cars/"+id
                    let token=localStorage.getItem('token')
                   axios.delete(url,{headers:{Authorization:'Bearer '+token, 'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'}})
                    //axios.delete(url, payload, config)
                    .then(({data,status}) => {
                        if(status === 200){
                            resolve(true);
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error=> {
                        reject(error);
                    })
                }); }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at https://restfulapi.net/http-status-codes/ you'll see that 401 stands for 'Unauthorized', which means that your `localStorage.getItem('token')` is returning something that is not acceptable for your backend, try checking what it is returning to make sure everything is fine.

Comment: My backend see null instead of token (printed by simple sout in controller). I don't know why and only in this case, because other requests like patch/get which I;m sending simultaneously works great and token is present... only in delete is not present...

Comment: You can check the localStorage itself, maybe in this case, the token could be deleted or something.

Comment: Token is present in local storage

Comment: But now I can compare my patch request with delete request and in patch request token is present in request header but in delete request is not.. I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

I also got the 401 response even though I had token in localstorage. But after adding

> 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

to my header I got 200 OK. Hope it will help you too.

```
axios.delete(`yourURL`, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("your_token")}` 
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

For **DELETE** requests, ensure to add the `data` and `headers` config. See the example below:

```
await axios.delete(`${serverURL}/locations/delete`, {
  data: {
    foo: "bar,
  },
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
  },
});
```